# What does this Scala type-parameter declaration mean? [A:B]

Tags: scala, types, declaration, traits

Recently I've seen a trait that resembles this definition:

```
trait Server[T, Reader[_], Writer[_]] {
  def read[Result:Reader](t: T): Result
  def write[Result:Writer](r: Result): T
}
```

(The [original definition](https://github.com/lihaoyi/autowire/blob/master/shared/main/scala/autowire/ClientServer.scala) is taken from the ["autowire" project](https://github.com/lihaoyi/autowire))

What does the `[Result:Reader]` and `[Result:Writer]` parts mean, exactly?

How is it to be interpreted? What is the relationship between Reader, Writer and Result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Result - type parametrization for read and write methods. It can be T, but T is already used in trait definition, so author picked a bit longer name for type parameter.

:Reader and :Writer - means that it should Reader and Writer type classes in scope for type Result

More about context bounds can be found here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html

This can be rewritten in this way:

```
trait Server[T, Reader[_], Writer[_]] {
  def read[Result](t: T)(implicit reader: Reader[Result]): Result
  def write[Result](r: Result)(implicit writer: Writer[Result]): T
}
```

However it's a little strange that Result is not used at all in trait definition. But totally ok.

Comment: *":Reader and :Writer - means that it should Reader and Writer type classes in scope for type Result"* -- Never heard of this. What's the name of this feature? Do you have a link where I can learn more?

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html - What is a Context Bound. It was introduced in scala 2.8.0 and I think starting from 2.10 used much more often than old-style implicits